Anet ET4 Pro temp problem
I got a printer and the bed and hot end both show the temperature is at 128 °C at room temperature.  I believe it's a problem with the main board. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?
Printer: Anet ET4 Pro

Has this suddenly occurred? Is it out of the box/brand new? Did you alter the firmware? Did you move the printer ? Have you checked the cables? Please provide some more context that might explain the thermistors showing the incorrect temperatures.
